# Can I query 2 columns to return 1 row in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

The company database has duplicate entries for ID due to different locations so I'm trying to return the database queries on the website by ID # AND zip matches. I can get the the code to query the database and not return an error but it won't return the values in the results(only blank entries) from the row it found.

Any ideas?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}        
$searchTerm = $_GET['term']; // GET the search term submitted by the form
$zip = $_GET['term1'];
            $customerNumber = '';
            $progID = '';
            $balance = '';



            $sql = "Select cust_no, zip From teecust where cust_no=? and zip=?";

            // Create the prepared statement
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $searchTerm, $zip); // bind the search term to the query where the '?' once was
                if(!$stmt->execute()){ // run the query
    echo $mysqli->error;
    }; 
                $stmt->bind_result($customerNumber, $progID, $balance); // retrieve results into variables
                while($stmt->fetch()){ // loop through results
                    // You now have the result in $customerNumber, $progID, and $balance - do what    you want with it
echo "Customer number: " . $customerNumber . "<br>Date last updated on: " . $progID . "<br> Balance: <strong>$" . $balance . "</strong> ";
                }
                $stmt->close();
            }
        else{
        echo $mysqli->error;
        }

            ?>
```

Comment: You are selecting 2 columns `cust_no, zip`, but trying to bind 3 results `$customerNumber, $progID, $balance`? Try removing `$balance` from `$stmt->bind_result($customerNumber, $progID, $balance);`

Comment: wow, that did it! Now I just need to  find a way to fill the rest with data from the rows

Comment: @Sean: Sounds like your comment might be well suited as an answer as well.